# Web scraping in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

is there any Objective C library for parsing HTML, like python's BeautifulSoup? Thanks

Comment: See [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Apple's part there is [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which support tidied HTML input. ([Tree-Based XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/CreatingXMLDoc.html))

On iOS (4.3) there's currently no [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) available, so you'd have to use either [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or libxml2.2.

Some more informations on potential problems with parsing malformed HTML:
[What's the best approach for parsing XML/'screen scraping' in iOS? UIWebview or NSXMLParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541615/whats-the-best-approach-for-parsing-xml-screen-scraping-in-ios-uiwebview-or-n/3541965#3541965)

**The most reliable solution is to use an off-screen WebView, load the HTML source into it and then access its DOM tree**.

Comment: Not to say you're wrong about any of the rest, but [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) _is_ available on iOS.

Comment: You're absoutely right. I had added NSXMLParser to my answer afterwards. Will rephrase it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

The best way I have found is `NSXMLParser` + `libtidy`. However, there are many third party libraries are available now which makes parsing easier. (last answer was written in 2011).

- Google's [Gumbo HTML5 parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) is pretty good. It's written in pure C99 and you can use it with Objective C (use a wrapper like [this one](https://github.com/programmingthomas/ObjectiveGumbo)).
- If you want pure Objective C libraries then [Ono](https://github.com/mattt/Ono) or [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) are good. [HTMLReader](https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader) is also a good alternative.
- If Swift is your thing, you could use [NDHpple](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple) which is a swift wrapper based on hpple. Or You could use [Swift-HTML-Parser](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Swift-HTML-Parser). (Bonus: [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) is as good as Python Requests and is a joy to use)