# working with urls in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, url

Is it possible to get information from a url?

For example, it would be possible to get the headline and the image through the following url:

http://www.farodevigo.es/deportes/2011/08/24/lopez-garai-herrera-equivoca-prescindiendo/574038.html

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541615/whats-the-best-approach-for-parsing-xml-screen-scraping-in-ios-uiwebview-or-n

Answer (score 0):

Try this - [What's the best approach for parsing XML/'screen scraping' in iOS? UIWebview or NSXMLParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541615/whats-the-best-approach-for-parsing-xml-screen-scraping-in-ios-uiwebview-or-n)

also http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is *possible* but I wouldn't reccommend it.

In general, parsing HTML is hard - it's probably badly formatted and you would have a hassle trying to work out which bits you wanted and which bits you didn't.

You are better off using this URL : `http://www.farodevigo.es/elementosInt/rss/1` and using NSXMLParser - because it's RSS it's definitely going to be well formed and easy for you to understand :)

Comment: (I can't read the language it's in so I'm not 100% sure that link is exactly the correct one but you should be able to find a RSS feed that contains what you need!)