# xmlparser and ASCII characters in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am facing  a parser problem in my project.I am getting data from an xml,In that I have special characters like &amp,%20....I would like to convert those symbols into the regular characters like &,space( ) . Kindly help me to solve this problem.

I know one way,is we need to replace the &amp with &.But is there any parser properties to convert those special characters into symbols?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602693/ios-html-unicode-to-nsstring

Answer (score 2):

duplicate of [Objective C HTML escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)

as per suggestion of Michael Waterfall in that post..

we have some categories of NSString for escaping the html tags, download [here](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m)

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```