# Encoding NSString containing 3 byte ASCII characters to a proper NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring, unicode-string

A JSON request returns strings with an HTML encoded Unicode character.

It looks like this: `valószín&#369;` which should be decoded to `valószínű`

In other words `&#369;` should be `ű`.

I found a description about a list of non-standard HTML characters here:
http://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html

Is there any easy way to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the string is partially escaped. If you encode "valószín&#369" into an NSData object using:

NSData * data = [@"valószín&#369" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

then created an attributed string using

NSAttributedString * attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:data documentAttributes:nil];

the "u" will be properly converted, but the preceding marks would be mangled:

resulting in

valÃ³szÃ­nű

An alternative would be to see the following post:

[iOS HTML Unicode to NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602693/ios-html-unicode-to-nsstring)

Comment: I would investigate why the JSON is coming back like it is.